# Umbraco 7 Modal popup closing when submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, umbraco

I have an application in Umbraco MVC 7, I have a button that call for Modal popup to open the login form. here is the modal code placed on partial view.

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage

@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using ClientDependency.Core.Mvc
@using Umbraco.Web
@using Umbraco.Web.Models
@using Umbraco.Web.Controllers

@{
    var loginModel = new LoginModel();

    Html.EnableClientValidation();
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();
    Html.RequiresJs("/umbraco_client/ui/jquery.js");
    Html.RequiresJs("/umbraco_client/Application/JQuery/jquery.validate.min.js");
    Html.RequiresJs("/umbraco_client/Application/JQuery/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js");
}

@Html.RenderJsHere()

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Login</h4>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<UmbLoginController>("HandleLogin", null, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 formError">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary()
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => loginModel.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => loginModel.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I don't type anything and clicks submit it keeps the modal open and display the validation error, all good, however if I type a wrong credentials its close the modal popup, instead I would like to keep open and display the returned error. I know it is not submitting because if I try to refresh the browser, it asks me to resend the form.

Any suggestion on what do I need to do to fix it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is no validation errors the form get submitted hence a page reload happens that's why the modal popup gets closed.

Solution :- You need to submit the login form using AJAX, so that only that part of the page will get submitted.